# Find most recent row using a conditional

Tags: r

I have a data frame consisting of lines in a conversation, similar to the first 5 columns below. Most lines are sequential, but sometimes there is overlap where a person starts typing before the previous utterance has been sent.

```
s2.df <- tibble(subj = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1),
                utt = c("Hi","How r u?","Good","Bad","Okay",
                        "Great!","You?","Okay!"),
                prev_subj = c(NA,"same","diff","same","same","diff",
                              "diff","diff"),
                utt_start_time = c(1,4,5,9,11,9,17,19),
                utt_end_time =   c(3,6,8,10,12,11,18,20),
                last_utt = c(NA,'Hi','Hi','Good','Bad','Good','Okay','You?'))
```

I am trying to generate the `last_utt` column, where the last utterance is the most recently sent message that was sent before the current line started. For example, the line `"Good"` began during `"How r u?"`, and so the most recent sent message was `"Hi"`.

In short, I am trying to find the last (most "recent") row where `utt_start_time` is greater than `utt_end_time`. I have tried doing this with `data.table::rleid` and `lag`, but wasn't able to find the correct solution.

Comment: Is `last_utt ` in your data.frame is right ? case `utt_start_time` equals 17 message is is not `Great!` ?

Comment: Yes. Which row are you unsure about?

Comment: Row 7 message ‘ Okay’

Comment: Row 5 was sent at time 12. This is the most recent previous time to 17, when row 7 was started.

Comment: I probably should've sorted the df by time_sent, but the data would still be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to map each value of `utt_start_time` to the entire column of `utt_end_time`. Return the index of the maximum `utt_end_time` which is less than the mapped value of `utt_start_time`. And then get `utt` for that particular index.

```r
library(tidyverse)

s2.df %>%
  arrange(utt_start_time) %>%
  mutate(last_utt2 = map_chr(utt_start_time, function(x){

    if(x > 1) {
      u <- utt[max(which(utt_end_time < x))]
    } else {
      u <- NA
    }
    
    return(u)
  }))

#--------
# A tibble: 8 x 7
   subj utt      prev_subj utt_start_time utt_end_time last_utt last_utt2
  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>              <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    
1     1 Hi       NA                     1            3 NA       NA       
2     1 How r u? same                   4            6 Hi       Hi       
3     2 Good     diff                   5            8 Hi       Hi       
4     2 Bad      same                   9           10 Good     Good     
5     1 Great!   diff                   9           11 Good     Good     
6     2 Okay     same                  11           12 Bad      Bad      
7     2 You?     diff                  17           18 Okay     Okay     
8     1 Okay!    diff                  19           20 You?     You?
```

---

Slight tweak so the data don't have to be sorted. Using `base` functions.

```r
sapply(s2.df$utt_start_time, function(x) {
  
  y <- s2.df$utt_end_time
  u <- s2.df$utt
  
  z <- u[which.max(y[which(y < x)])]
  
  if(length(z) == 0) NA else z
  
})
```

Or with the tweak but using `dplyr`

```
s2.df %>%
  mutate(last_utt2 = map_chr(utt_start_time, function(x){
    
    u <- utt[which.max(utt_end_time[which(utt_end_time < x)])]
   
    if(x <= min(utt_start_time)) NA else u
    
  }))
```

---

Broken down a bit more

```
# which utt_end_time values are less than the given start_time
less_than_list <- lapply(s2.df$utt_start_time, function(x) which(s2.df$utt_end_time < x))

# which utt_end_time is the highest of those
max_less_than_index <- lapply(less_than_list, function(x) which.max(s2.df$utt_end_time[x]))

# utt value for the given index
s2.df$last_utt3 <- sapply(max_less_than_index, function(x) if(length(x) == 0) NA else s2.df$utt[x])
```

---

Input data

```
library(tibble)
s2.df <- tibble(subj = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,2,1),
                utt = c("Hi","How r u?","Good","Bad","Okay",
                        "Great!","You?","Okay!"),
                prev_subj = c(NA,"same","diff","same","same","diff",
                              "diff","diff"),
                utt_start_time = c(1,4,5,9,11,9,17,19),
                utt_end_time =   c(3,6,8,10,12,11,18,20),
                last_utt = c(NA,'Hi','Hi','Good','Bad','Good','Okay','You?'))
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is great! Could you explain this part a little bit?   `utt[max(which(.$utt_end_time < x))]`

Comment: The `.` is shorthand for the sorted `s2.df` in this pipe. `max(which())` returns the last index of values which are `TRUE`. And then `utt[i]` returns `utt` for the given index.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong about needing the `.$` notation. Played around with a couple other configurations, but all basically the same idea

Comment: Thank you so much for this further help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: When I'm using grouped data, I get the error `Error in mutate():
! Problem while computing last_utt2 = map_chr(...).
ℹ The error occurred in group 2: exp_id = "E070".
Caused by error in stop_bad_type():
! Result 2 must be a single string, not a character vector of length 0`. I've tried adding the `.$` back in to explicitly declare it, but that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Best guess from the message is that in group `E070` there is non character data in the `utt` column. `map_chr` is stopping when it hits that row. You could try `map` instead. Or force `utt` to character before running the function

Comment: Or maybe it's the if statement at the end not catching a "character vector of length zero" and replacing it with `NA`